# How to use bootstrap with reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie in React.js and since I began to read documents and tutorials, I am not sure how does Bootstrap work with React.js.

I saw a couple of npm packages such as `reactstrap` or `react-bootstrap`, however, I don't get it. The HTML code comes from a method that returns a piece of HTML (like this):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

*If I'm right...*

So, my question is either:

- Should I add the `<link/>` or `<script/>` of Bootstrap into index.html, either into body or into header?

or

- Do I have to include Bootstrap from my `App.js` file and use it from a method?

PS: *I am developing for years now but I never did any Javascript/HTML/CSS web, so if you have any advice, thanks in advance!*

I need to use the logic of Bootstrap grid in order to realize an HCI

Thanks for any help

Comment: all you need is to add Bootstrap in react right? if so you need to add css cdn in `index.html`

Comment: But if I add from my index.html, how to use it from the js side?

Comment: Future readers using Bootstrap 5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941329/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, both of your suggestions on your questions are correct. You can do it either way.

1. Include `bootstrap CDN` in your `index.html`
2. You can add bootstrap packages such as [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) using `npm`/`yarn` and import required components into you `App.js`

If you do it first way all you need to do is add your [**Bootstrap CDN**](https://getbootstrap.com/) in `index.html` and when you access your class in Javascript, it will be working fine

> **NOTE**: While accessing class in react use `className` and not `class`

Here is an example of how you add CDN in your `index.html`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} >
        <label>
          Name:
        </label> 
        <input type = "text" className="form-control"
          value = {this.state.value}
          onChange = {this.handleChange}/> 
        <input type = "submit"
          value = "Submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>
     </form> 
   </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id='root'></div>
```

---

**EDIT:-**
Assuming you installed React according to [Official Installation](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#trying-out-react)

Use the following file structure

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <!-- And then your bundled js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/app'; //Make sure it's the path to your App.js

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

*src/components/app.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} >
          <label>
            Name:
          </label> 
          <input type = "text" className="form-control"
            value = {this.state.value}
            onChange = {this.handleChange}/> 
          <input type = "submit"
          value = "Submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check this, it should work.

Comment: Can you just specify where you put the code (exactly)? I put the first part into `App.js` and the second one into `intel.html`'s body and, the design doesn't seem like yours :/

Comment: How have you installed react? If it's according to the official documentation , then you add 1st part in `App.js` and 2nd in `index.html`.  But you will need to figure out as you might need to do some changes in `index.js`. Better if you can put your code on github and I can see it and make some necessary changes to it.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, Hi Dhaval, I just wanted to ask, which way should we use in order to use Bootstrap in React project. Is it true that we need to use Bootstrap cdn during development but during production we need to use bootstrap package installed in React project. Please can you give your professional advice. Thank you. Peace be with you:)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, please Dhaval I really need your help:(

Comment: @Dickens, hey sorry was preoccupied with something.
You can use the CDN or reference the downloaded Bootstrap CSS and JS file in production.
Bootstrap is backed by Twitter and hence there are fewer chances of them deprecating bootstrap CDN in the near future, but if you want to be safe you can download the packages or as I mentioned in the answer as well use `react-bootstrap`

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, thank you Dhaval for your kind explanation:D. Dhaval, if you were in my shoes, for real projects would you download bootstrap package rather than linking CDN?:). I just kindly want to know which way you would use personally according to your experience

Comment: I would download the packages and use it rather than CDN :)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Is there any difference between React Bootstrap and the vanilla bootstrap in Javascript? Also, do I include the import bootstrap in `index.js` or `App.js`?

Comment: React Bootstrap is more component-based, so they provide you with components like `<Button>`, whereas in regular bootstrap you add style into className.

Import regular bootstrap into `/public/index.html`(your main file) or `React-Bootstrap` as npm and then import components as needed. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/