# Use Bootstrap with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I'm new and currently learning React. I just wanted to ask if I wanted to use Bootstrap 4 with my React app, do I have to install jQuery? I read somewhere that using jQuery with React is a NO-NO. So now I'm wondering. Thanks for the reply. Your advice and suggestions are truly appreciated.

Comment: You do need jQuery for some Bootstrap functionality (like list-item tabs, etc.) but it should be okay without it. If you *do* want the full functionality of Bootstrap in a React app, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-on-reactjs).

Comment: Im trying to avoid using JQuery with react since its a bad practice according to what I have read so far. But there's a theme in bootstrap 4 that I want to use so Im wondering if JQuery is necessary for me to use that theme.

Comment: As said by Jack jQuery is only for some intercation with components so you could figure it out without. However you can use the css part, have a look at this [article](https://m.pardel.net/react-and-bootstrap-4-part-1-setup-navigation-d4767e2ed9f0).
Ps : `@import "~bootstrap"`

Comment: https://reactstrap.github.io/ seems to be a react port of the JS part of bootstrap 4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Certain functionalities such as dropdown, modal requires JS to manipulate the DOM, and bootstrap uses jQuery to handle the DOM manipulations.

However, React uses [virtual DOM](https://hackernoon.com/virtual-dom-in-reactjs-43a3fdb1d130), so manipulating the browser DOM outside your React app through jQuery means React is potentially no longer handling state, events and UI rendering. And React broadly expects/assumes that nothing else will be modifying the DOM.

---

This is why [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) or [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) are recommended. The CSS remains exactly the same, but the components that initially require jQuery are rewritten.

Take [this bootstrap 4 modal](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) as example, you need to define `modal` state which determines whether the modal is being shown or hidden.

So essentially these react bootstrap libraries rewrite each bootstrap component into a React component, CSS wise it's entirely the same.

Comment: react-bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) now supports bootstrap version 4.5

Comment: @coder247 thank you for the reminder. this answer was written when react-bootstrap only supports bootstrap v3. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking to use react-bootstrap. Instead, you can install it using npm: $npm install --save react-bootstrap [Find more about it on this link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)

just remember that it uses the  Bootstrap v3.

Happy coding!

Comment: There's active work to get it to work with Bootstrap 4 and can be tracked at https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/projects/1

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2020 - Bootstrap 5**

Bootstrap 5 no longer requires jQuery and is [modular](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#using-bootstrap-as-a-module) so you can @import it like any other JS module which makes it easier to use with React. It also means you can use Bootstrap *without* a 3rd party library like reactstrap or react-bootstrap.

Also, you can import components and reference them directly. For example:

```
const popover = new Popover(document.querySelector('#myButton'), options)
```

This makes it easier to use Bootstrap 5 with the React 16.8+ `useEffect` and `useState` hooks. So that we avoid direct DOM manipulation in React, get the element instance with a `useRef` hook...

```
function PopoverDemo() {
  const popoverRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    var popover = new Popover(popoverRef.current, {
        content: "Hello popover content!",
        title: "My Popover",
        trigger: 'hover'
    })
  })

  return (
    <div className="py-2">
        <button className="btn btn-danger" ref={popoverRef}>
            Hover for popover
        </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Bootstrap 5 with React Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/SfIG4ZsBIc)