# Integrating regular bootstrap into react without using the react-bootstrap library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I do not want to rewrite my bootstrap admin templates to work with react-bootstrap library. I just want to use my bootstrap components in react. All the bootstrap css stuff works in react but none of the actions do. For instance a simple data-toggle in bootstrap is not working in react.

I know react has uncontrolled components. PLEASE could someone show me how I can use this to get a simple data-toggle in bootstrap to work in react.

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar" aria-label="Hide Sidebar"></a>
<div data-toggle="sidebar">TOGGLE ME</div>
```

Comment: I tried to follow: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9087/integrate-admin-template-in-reactjs

Comment: you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941329/use-bootstrap-4-with-react

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular Bootstrap with react by installing bootstrap via `npm i bootstrap --save` in your project folder.

Don't forget to also import bootstrap in your index.js file.
You can do so by: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`