# Navbar is not showing up on mobile

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive, bootstrap-5

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="`enter code here`">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Linkedin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">GitHub</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Email</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is the navbar in html made with BootStrap. but somehow it does not show up on the mobile any tips of how to change this? I have tried a lot and I looked over previous questions aswell but nothing helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)...

> "Navbars can use .navbar-toggler, .navbar-collapse, and
> .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl} classes to determine when their
> content collapses behind a button"

Your code is missing the toggler...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="`enter code here`">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Linkedin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">GitHub</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Email</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/vd3qFDtOKI)

---

Also note the [data attributes have changed in Bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341620/navbar-dropdown-menu-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-5/65341807#65341807)

Comment: The toggle button shows up but when I click it there is no response! Any idea how can I fix it?