# Bootstrap + Django navbar not opening on toggle

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, nav, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to use the collapsible navbar component provided by bootstrap.

I believe I am not importing the correct libraries.

Here is my base.html

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Course!</title>
</head>


<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my navbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        Navbar
    </a>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am sure that the error is actually in base.html itself where I am not importing the correct scripts.
Additionally, if it would be greatly appreciated if I could get advice on how to store these files locally.

Comment: Have a look here for the CDN's: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navbar dropdown Menu is not working in Bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341620/navbar-dropdown-menu-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-5)

Comment: @Zim I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in attribute `data-toggle` and `data-target` you are using `bootstrap-5` CDN and in bootstrap-5 we use `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` attribute

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Course!</title>
</head>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        Navbar
    </a>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

for more information https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

Comment: This didn't seem to solve the issue. I have just downgraded to v4 now.

Comment: this solved the problem for me! just can't copy/paste out of bootstraps docs without modifying the `data-` attrs.