# Why isn't my dropdown menu working as expected?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I don't understand why it's not working. Thanks for your help.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href=" {% url 'home' %} ">Newspaper</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> {{ user.username }} </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341620/navbar-dropdown-collapse-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your data attribute names to the appropriate ones for Bootstrap 5.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href=" {% url 'home' %} ">Newspaper</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> {{ user.username }} </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try changing the div tags around your dropdown and using the select tags as shown below :

```html
<select class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</select>
```

Comment: it didin't work

Comment: You should also change your <a></a> tags to <option></option> tags, remove the "class" declaration and add an "id" in the first <select> tag

Comment: @doriandevtech, all information should be in your answer, not down here in comments. Do note that they are using Bootstrap, so it probably shouldn't be a select element.

Comment: now it worked but it seemslike old scholl not bootsrap like apperience

Answer (score 0):

*Check out this code*

*Run code snippet in full page*

```html
<head>
  <link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href=" {% url 'home' %} ">Newspaper</a>

    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown"> 
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            {{ user.username }}
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button
        class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton1"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        User.username
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with some explanation. Also, you haven't fixed the faulty attribute names, so the menu still doesn't work. I'm not sure why you added a dropdown that wasn't in the original code.